# paypal doesnt go through ask shipping statement if lower then 30

Tags: html, paypal, web

I use this code to see if value of donation is above 30 then ask for shipping and if not then dont ask for shipping but when i enter a value less then 30 paypal doesnt go through

```
   function askShipping(){
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    if(amount == ''){
        alert('Please enter Donation amount');
        return false;
    }
    if(amount >= 30){
        var ret = shipSuccess();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
function shipSuccess(){
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-success" ).dialog({
        height: 260,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "yes": function(){
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                shippingForm();
                // document.donationForm.submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                document.donationForm.submit();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to work out what your problem is from the code you posted, since you don't explain which piece of code actually submits the information to PayPal.

However, I'm going to take a punt on the answer being that your `askShipping()` function should look like this:

```
function askShipping () {
    if ($("#amount").val() == '') {
        alert('Please enter Donation amount');
    } else if (amount >= 30) {
        shipSuccess();
    } else {
        document.donationForm.submit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this fixes your problem, let me know in comments and I'll explain why... ;-)